# How to check value that I am trying to insert in database already exists

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have randomly generated barcodes that are stored in database. I need to check if the barcode that I'm trying to insert already exists, and if exist i need to generate different one.

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\PC\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp26\WindowsFormsApp26\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1](press, date, barcode)  VALUES  ( '" + ardVrednost + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + bar + "'   )", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I was searching everywhere but did not find a solution to my problem

Comment: Have a look at `Merge` SQL command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: that can be done  by retrieving all barcodes and checking all retrieved barcodes one by one if that barcode matches generated one or not ,if it matches generate new else insert.

Comment: Do you have an index on that column? You could add it, and catch the corresponding error.

Comment: Avinash can you show me an example on how could i do that , Please

Comment: Randomly generated barcode? Don't you use a certain pattern to generate the barcodes?

Comment: Yeah i use like , the year , 3 randomly generated numbers , the date , 4 randlomly generated numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following

```
cmd = new Sqlcommand($@"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Table1] WHERE barcode = {bar}",con);
var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(result == "1"){ 
    //do generate new barcode
}
```

since you don't provide a database schema, I assume that you might use barcode as unique key.

Comment: no, you asked for 'check if the barcode that I'm trying to insert already exists' so it not depends on C# itself, it's a database-related problem as my code suggest you to query for 'current generated barcode' to see if it already exist in database (by count the row where barcode = generated barcode) if the query return 1 it's mean that barcode is already exist then you can try generate new barcode and insert it into database.

Comment: yes this will work but ask yourself if its efficient. If you only have a few thousand rows it wont matter offcourse. Have you googled the term `Upsert` already ?

Comment: Is there a risk here that before the new bar-code is created, another user gets in just before and makes the same bar-code, before it's written to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if a barcode must be unique than make an unique constraint on your database.

Now to answer this first you must ask yourself how often will the system try to insert a barcode that is already there.

If this happens only a few times, then its more efficient to just do the insert and catch the exception from your unique constraint.

If it happens alot then it will be more efficient to `Update` the barcode, and if that fails because it does not exist then insert it.

So if you know that the barcode will exists most of the times, then doing an update will work most of the time. Thus your database calls will be kept to the bare minimum making it more efficient since most of the time you will need only one call to your database

Comment: It will be very often , the project is like going to parking and you press a button and barcode is printed and later on you can pay your ticket ,

Comment: So that means the update will not often fail. So trie to update first and only do insert when the update fails

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a list first.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

Then retrieve all the barcode values from database into your list.

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\PC\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp26\WindowsFormsApp26\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT press,date,barcode FROM [Table1])", con);
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(reader.GetString(2));
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
```

And in the end just matches your new barcode from the above list to see if it is already present in the database or not.

```
If(list.Contains(barcode))
{
    //do not insert the value in the database
}
else
{
   //Your Insert query
}
```

Comment: One question Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SqlDataReader' and 'string'

Comment: This is the slowest way to do this - you don't want to do it this way you are throwing away one of the major benefits to having a database. If you index your barcode field, the "exists" check will be very quick, the above could be up to orders of magnitude slower since you are pulling all the data from the database layer to the c# application and looping through the whole lot!

Comment: @Charleh This is only an example for a beginner to better understand the concepts of c#.

Comment: @Ivanh23 The list is of type string and the Contains method also takes a string. If your bar/barcode variable is of type SqlDataReader then convert it into string using ToString().

Comment: @WasifMahmoodMustafa beginners should learn about databases too and learn the right way to do things instead of learning bad habits